# OpenCV fitLine exceptions

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV `fitLine()` function.

Sometimes following exception are thrown:

```
..\opencv\modules\core\src\matrix.cpp:1219: error: (-215) 
dims == 2 && ((size[0] == sz.height && size[1] == sz.width) || (allocateVector 
&& size[0] == sz.width && size[1] == sz.height)) in function create
```

Also some assertions are failed:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims == 2 && ((size[0] == sz.height &&
size[1] == sz.width) || (allocateVector && size[0] == sz.width && 
size[1] == sz.height))) in create
```

Has someone similiar issues? Maybe points are too bad for fitting line? Should I change `fitLine()` function parameters?

Code

```
cv::Vec4f newLine;
if(temp.size() >= 2)
{
    qDebug()<<"Correcting line";
    std::vector<cv::Point2f> temp2;
    for(std::vector<std::pair<cv::Point2f,float> >::iterator i = temp.begin();
        i != temp.end(); i++)
    {
        temp2.push_back((*i).first);
    }
    qDebug()<<"temp2 size: "<<temp2.size();
    try{
        cv::fitLine(temp2,newLine,CV_DIST_HUBER,0,0.01,0.01);
    }
    catch(cv::Exception e)
    {
        qDebug()<<e.what();
    }
```

I've changed `Vec4f newLine` to `std::vector<float> newLine(4)` and it works. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

those assertion are just there to check the dimensions of your data are correct (eg, set of 2D or 3D points). So if they are raised, you have probably not correctly initialised your data, but I cannot tell without the code

Comment: Changed `Vec4f newLine to `std::vector<float> newLine[4] and everything works. Why?

Comment: it does not work with newLine as Vec4f but does work with newLine as vector<float> ? Not sure why. fitLine expects a OutputArray argument, not sure what are the compatibilities btw OutputArray, VecXf, and vector<float>

Comment: The code I've posted is done in loop. First loop iteration ends ok with Vec4f, second and next throws error. With vector<float> there is no such a problem. I don't know whats the issue cause `Vec4f newLine` is defined in loop and should be local for each loop iteration?

Comment: Then you probably have a memory corruption somewhere in your program causing the erratic behavior. Try profiling your memory usage, e.g. using valgrind on Linux

Answer (score 0):

This exception is generate by empty Mat, so check is empty or not:

```
    if (locations.rows != 0 ) {
        //do stuff
    }
```